# Is it possible to forbid an image to go beyond the view without giving a size?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have mission to make modal view that takes a half of a screen with image background.

The image should be animated (rotation animation).

The image has size 1920*1080, so it's not circle.

I create a view with heigh = screen height/2 and give some border radius.
And when I Start animate the image , The image goes beyond the boundaries of the view instead of rotating within it.

```
export const PurchaseWorldAndLevelModal = ({isVisible}) => {

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(isVisible);

    return (
        <Modal
            style={{width: layout.width, height: layout.height * 0.3}}
            visible={isVisible}
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}>

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={assets.MODAL_BACKGROUND} style={styles.imageBackgroundStyle} blurRadius={10}/>
            </View>

        </Modal>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        bottom: 0,
        width: layout.width,
        height: layout.height * 0.3,
        elevation: 1,
        zIndex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        ...layout.shadowOfPinnedItem,
    },
    imageBackgroundStyle: {
        width: layout.width * 2,
        
        height: layout.height * 0.3,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 50,
        borderTopRightRadius: 50,
    },
    modalView: {
        margin: 20,
        padding: 35,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

Here is what I have for now:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the rotation animation and corresponding styling, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Hi @digitalbreed,

It's enough to add transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }] to the image to get this result